# cannot bind on a new display member combobox c#

Tags: winforms, combobox

When I run my program on my machine it works totally fine but when I run the code from other machine, I get an Error that says "Cannot bind on a new display member"? I just don't understand why? Here is my code.

```
  private DataTable effectivity, filesTable, cgmFiles;

  private void FillEffectivity()
  {
        cbEffectivity.ComboBox.DataSource = null;
        effectivity = FillDataTable("SELECT * FROM Projects ORDER BY Project ASC");
        cbEffectivity.ComboBox.DataSource = effectivity;
        cbEffectivity.ComboBox.DisplayMember = "project";
        cbEffectivity.ComboBox.ValueMember = "RecNo";
  }

  private DataTable FillTable(string sql)
  {                      
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, cn))
            {
                da.Fill(table);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex.Message == "Not a valid password.")
            {
                SetPassword();
                return FillTable(sql);
            }
            return new DataTable();
        }
        finally
        {
            cn.Close();
        }
        return table;
  }
```

Comment: Most probably the other machine is hitting `return new DataTable();` line. This is very bad coding practice because you are hiding the actual problem. Replace that line with `throw;` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like problem in your query instead of `effectivity = FillDataTable("SELECT * FROM Projects ORDER BY Project ASC");` try `FillDataTable("SELECT * FROM Projects ORDER BY project ASC");`

also it is recommended that dont use * while selecting it will affect on performance. 
 try this

```
 FillDataTable("SELECT project FROM Projects ORDER BY project ASC");
```